# Where should i put Axios baseUrl conf in sveltekit project?

Tags: axios, sveltekit, rest-client

All is in the title, more specially i am using the orval rest client generator. In the doc it says that you can configure baseUrl for axios.But i don't realy know where i should put this kind of config in a svletekit project, index.js maybe ?

[https://orval.dev/guides/set-base-url#:~:text=Axios.defaults.baseURL%20%3D%20%27%3CBACKEND%20URL%3E%27%3B%20//%20use%20your%20own%20URL%20here%20or%20environment%20variable](https://orval.dev/guides/set-base-url#:%7E:text=Axios.defaults.baseURL%20%3D%20%27%3CBACKEND%20URL%3E%27%3B%20//%20use%20your%20own%20URL%20here%20or%20environment%20variable)

Answer (score 0):

Axios seems to have a setting so:

- If `baseUrl` is `https://api.example.com`
- A request for `/endpoint/path/` will get `https://api.example.com/endpoint/path/`

---

First of all, don't use Axios with SvelteKit. SvelteKit has a special version of [`fetch()`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/web-standards#fetch-apis) that should be used instead.

SvelteKit (`fetch()`) does not have a setting like `axios.baseURL`.

- So you must call external API's with the full path.
- Internal API's may be called with relative requests.

---

You may write a custom wrapper around SvelteKit's `fetch()` that accomplishes the same thing as `axios.baseURL`. Write a function that takes the `fetch()` function as input, and outputs a custom fetch that uses a base URL:

```
const makeFetchWithBaseUrl = (fetchFunction, baseUrl) => {
    // Return a function with same the signature as fetch().
    return (resource, options) => {
        // If resource is a string that doesn't start with 'http' prepend baseUrl.
        if (typeof resource === 'string' && /^http:/.test(resource)) {
            resource = baseUrl + resource
        }
        // Call the original fetch
        return fetchFunction(resource, options)
    }
}
```

Then you can use the function above like this:

```
// Make custom fetch function:
const exampleComFetch = makeFetchWithBaseUrl(fetch, 'https://example.com/')

// Then use it:
const response = await exampleComFetch('myEndpoint/path/')
```

Comment: There are some real life edge cases where `fetch` simply won't work. For example, sending a body with a `GET` request (which does not adhere to XHTTP standards, but might be needed in some edge cases) is just impossible with `fetch`, but possible with `axios`. Should you prefer `fetch` whenever possible? Certainly. Should you rule `axios` out entirely? Certainly not.